# what is the version of elasticsearch for nutch1.10?

Tags: nutch

I used nutch1.10 but i cannot find the appropriate version of elasticsearch for indexing.I used elasticsearch 2.4 but  the log of  elasticsearch  displays not support.so does 2.1.0 ?I want to konw what is the appropriate version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/branch-1.10/src/plugin/indexer-elastic/ivy.xml#L39 the correct version should be elasticsearch 1.4.1.

Comment: thanks a lot!!  I forgot add the cluster name in nutch-site.xml